# content_columns method is not returning the 'id' column in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to list down all the column details for a given table and I was able to do it with the following code

```
<Model Name>.content_columns
```

Ex: `User.content_columns`

But my problem is it is not returning the `id` column of the table (I have default rails naming convention as auto increment integer column called `id`)

Is there anyway of enabling the 'id' column or is this the default behavior of rails?

I'm riding Rails 3.0.10 on linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Model.columns.map(&:name)
```

should work fine.

Comment: Hi @lucapette, yes you are correct, just found that answer, but all the credit goes to you, and thanks for the speedy reply. thanks

Comment: @sameera207 More than welcome. Well please consider to accept the answer then :)

Comment: Hi @lucapette, I accepted your answer, BTW I wanted to accept your answer as soon as you posted but SF didnt allow me to do it until 8 ins :D